# When calling pytest on a directory, doesn't show captured stdout upon test failure

Tags: python, testing, pytest

If I use pytest on a singular test file:

`pytest -v tests/file_to_test.py`

Then my logger will be captured in stdout. However, if I run pytest on the whole directory of tests:

`pytest -v tests/file_to_test.py`

I do not get the captured stdout.

For the logging, I am using

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, stream=sys.stdout)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
...
logger.info('show in stdout')
```

and if I use a plain `print` statement, the captured stdout is shown.

I have tried `pytest-capturelog` and `pytest-catchlog` and neither work for me when I run the whole directory. Any ideas?

EDIT: `-s` also isn't want I am looking for here.

Comment: Were you able to find a workaround? I'm having a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a stream handler for the stdout and use it on logger configuration

```
stdout_handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
handlers = [stdout_handler]

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,handlers=handlers)
```

And then you need to run your tests with `-s` to show the logs

https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html?highlight=handlers#streamhandler